# Dashed loop in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, decorations

How can I draw a dashed loop in TikZ?  I tried

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (X) [circle, draw] {X};
  \draw (X) to [in=60, out=120, dashed, loop] ();
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, the `loop` only "listens" to the options `in` and `out`, but not to `dashed`.  The resulting loop is not dashed:

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well it seems you messed with drawing arguments. If you do

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node (X) [circle, draw] {X};
  \draw[dashed] (X) to [in=60, out=120, loop] ();
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You'll get a nice dashed loop:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, which fixes my problem, and to Jubobs for the pictures.